# Variable not hoisted

Tags: javascript, hoisting

In Javascript variables are hoisted to the top of the scope they are declared within.
However in the following code it seems that the variable `myvar` is not hoisted.

```
<html>
<body>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log(typeof myvar);  

    var myvar = "value";    

    console.log(typeof myvar);  

</script>
```

The output of the above is:

```
undefined
string
```

I expected that the first line would say "string" because `myvar` is supposed to be hoisted to above it.

Why isn't this so?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Variable *declarations* are hoisted, the *assignments* are not.

By using `var myvar` *anywhere in the function* you create a locally scoped variable `myvar`, but if you follow it with `= something` then the assignment will take place in normal code order.

Comment: I thought that "typeof variable" is the way to check if a variable is declared. So how can have some print that proves that myvar was indeed hoisted?

Comment: `typeof` will tell you the type that the *value* of variable is. To demonstrate hoisting, define another variable in a wider scope with the same name and a different value, then test to see if the values are different.

Comment: @kroiz—there is no way to tell if an identifier is a declared variable or not other than for globals, and only then because they are made properties of the global object.

Answer (score 2):

*A dupe of this came up, and Quentin's answer is good (as always), but just to spell it out even more:*

The way the JavaScript engine actually processes that code is like this:

```
// Before any step-by-step code
var myvar;
// Now step-by-step starts
console.log(typeof myvar);  // undefined since no value has been written to it
myvar = "value";    
console.log(typeof myvar);  // "value" because that's its value now
```

That is, this:

```
var myvar = "value";
```

... is actually two separate things that happen at two separate times. The *variable declaration* (the `var myvar` part), which happens before any step-by-step code in the scope is run, and the *initialization* (the `myvar = "value"` part; it's really an assignment expression by the time it's processed), which happens where that line is in the code.

Comment: I came here to make sure there was a good explanation and code example on this question from that same dup. Nicely done.